# split sentences in R where the email id's or decimal numbers need not be splitted

Tags: r, regex, string, split, strsplit

I want to split the paragraph into sentences by full stop or period. But while doing this the decimal numbers, email id's are also getting split into different dataframes. can anyone help me to split the data into sentences.

Eg:

```
aa = "For Important Disclosure information, please visit our website at 0.5%  https://javatar.bluematrix.com/sellside/Disclosures.action or call 1.888.JEFFERIES. An organization. 0.5% have an analysis."
```

this should be split into

1. `For Important Disclosure information, please visit our website at 0.5%  https://javatar.bluematrix.com/sellside/Disclosures.action or call 1.888.JEFFERIES.`
2. `An organization.`
3. `0.5% have an analysis`

code:

```
sentences = as.matrix(unlist(strsplit(aa,"\\.")))
```

Comment: Fyi, you can "accept" an answer as noted here if you want: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 5):

This looks like it is working:

```
strsplit(aa, '. ', fixed = TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "For Important Disclosure information, please visit our website at 0.5% https://javatar.bluematrix.com/sellside/Disclosures.action or call 1.888.JEFFERIES"
#[2] "An organization"                                                                                                                                          
#[3] "0.5% have an analysis."
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved me :)

Comment: Be careful though, there are other strings where this will fail, e.g. "Mr.", "Dr." "e.g." all are not sentence ends but do follow the pattern of having a period followed by a space. You may want to use something like `tokenize_sentences` from https://github.com/ropensci/tokenizers

Comment: Thanks Christoph, this is helpful. :)